# Echo php the_title within php variable?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, title

How do I echo:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

Within the variable below, after "q="

```
<?php
    $feedURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=<?php the_title(); ?>&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use here is `get_the_title()` [function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title).

The function you are using (`the_title()`) it is used to print the value (although you can force it to just return the value, [more info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title))

Your code would look like this:

```
<?php
    $feedURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' . get_the_title() . '&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2';
?>
```

Comment: +1 for explaining *why* and providing relevant links, instead of simple *"Try this `block of code`"*. . . . . . . . . . Well, for completeness, would be worth noting the concatenation issue as in Collin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<?php
    $feedURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' . get_the_title() . '&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2';
?>
```

Comment: Please see the updated answer, it should be "get_the_title" instead of "the_title" in WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$title = the_title(); 
    $feedURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='.urlencode($title).'&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're already in php, so you don't need to open php tags again. Simply concatenate the variable on the string.

```
<?php
    $feedURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' . the_title() . '&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2';
?>
```

Edited to use . instead of + to match PHP.

Comment: `+` isn't the concatenation operator in PHP, you need to use `.`.